# Blazor JsInterop DOM element reference

Tags: javascript, dom, blazor, interop, gridstack

We are currently working on a new Blazor Web app, and I'm in charge of porting a few JavaScript libraries that we are going to require. I have a port of gridstack.js working, but I'm not really that familiar with Blazor, and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing certaing things.

I will be posting code snippets, but if someone wants to look at the whole thing, it is [here](https://github.com/decelis/BlazorGridStack).

I'm using JsInterop to bring all methods and events of the JavaScript component to Blazor. But certain methods and events return a DOM element (HTMLElement or something of the sort), and sending this from the Js to the Blazor gives me the following error:

```
//JavaScript code
await interopReference.invokeMethodAsync("AddedFired", items.map(i => { i.el.gridstackNode = undefined; i.el.ddElement = undefined; return i.el; }));

//C# Code
[JSInvokable]
public void AddedFired(ElementReference[] widgets)
{
    Console.Write(widgets);
}
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.Text.Json.JsonException: __internalId is required.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReferenceJsonConverter.Read(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryRead(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCoreAsObject(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](:7283/JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Read[TValue](:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.ParseArguments(:7283/JSRuntime jsRuntime, String methodIdentifier, String arguments, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously(:7283/JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo& callInfo, IDotNetObjectReference objectReference, String argsJson)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.BeginInvokeDotNet(:7283/JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo invocationInfo, String argsJson)
    at kt.endInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.server.js:1:3700)
    at blazor.server.js:1:72054
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at kt._invokeClientMethod (blazor.server.js:1:72040)
    at kt._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1:70082)
    at connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js:1:64485)
    at o.onmessage (blazor.server.js:1:48819)
```

I tried with an array of IJSObjectReference instead of ElementReference, and I get a similar error

```
    Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.Text.Json.JsonException: Required property __jsObjectId not found.
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Implementation.JSObjectReferenceJsonWorker.ReadJSObjectReferenceIdentifier(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.JSObjectReferenceJsonConverter.Read(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryRead(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCoreAsObject(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](:7283/JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Read[TValue](:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(:7283/Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.ParseArguments(:7283/JSRuntime jsRuntime, String methodIdentifier, String arguments, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously(:7283/JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo& callInfo, IDotNetObjectReference objectReference, String argsJson)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.BeginInvokeDotNet(:7283/JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo invocationInfo, String argsJson)
    at kt.endInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.server.js:1:3700)
    at blazor.server.js:1:72054
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at kt._invokeClientMethod (blazor.server.js:1:72040)
    at kt._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1:70082)
    at connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js:1:64485)
    at o.onmessage (blazor.server.js:1:48819)
```

As of right now I am sending ids and element querys back and forth, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this in  blazor.

Thanks in advance!